# Swift & Xcode: UISlider will not respond in simulated build

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uislider

I am building a small disc golf scoring app to track two player's progress through the front nine. I think my logic is sound and the linter in Xcode is picking up no errors but my UISlider will not move in the simulated build and the associated string interpolation will not load. Can anyone help?

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  DiscGolfScoresheet

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateHole()
}

// Holes available to play
let frontNineList = ["Hole 1", "Hole 2", "Hole 3", "Hole 4", "Hole 5", "Hole 6", "Hole 7", "Hole 8", "Hole 9"]
// Counter to track current hole in play
var currentHoleIndex = 0
// UI elements grouped
@IBOutlet weak var holeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var oneScore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var oneSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var twoScore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var twoSlider: UISlider!
// Variables to track players' scores through the rounds
var oneCurrentScore = 0
var twoCurrentScore = 0


// Action to track slider/score changes for player one
@IBAction func oneSliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let oneCurrentScore = Int(sender.value)
    oneScore.text = "Player one's total score: \(oneCurrentScore)"
}

// Action to track slider/score changes for player two
@IBAction func twoSliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let twoCurrentScore = Int(sender.value)
    twoScore.text = "Player two's total score: \(twoCurrentScore)"
}

// Function to cycle through all nine holes with associated pictures and labels
func updateHole() {
    holeLabel.text = frontNineList[currentHoleIndex]
    let holePicture = frontNineList[currentHoleIndex]
    let image = UIImage(named: holePicture)
    imageView.image = image
}

// Function to go to next hole when button is selected and to cycle through indefinitely
@IBAction func goToNextHole(_ sender: Any) {
    currentHoleIndex += 1
    if currentHoleIndex >= frontNineList.count {
        currentHoleIndex = 0
    }
    updateHole()
}
```

}

Comment: Set the minimum value, maximum value as an integer to each slider.  Turn on the continuous updates switch on.

Comment: Minimum value is -3, maximum is 7, current is set to 0. Continuous updates are on.

Comment: You mentioned it's not working on the simulated build.  Does it work on a real device?

Comment: The most common reasons for UIKit widgets not responding are 1) User interaction enabled checkbox in Interface Builder is not checked, and 2) Another view, perhaps transparent, is in front of it.